# Hide part of one object's mesh while manipulating another object

Tags: vertices, masking

I have a character head, with all the face skin on one object and the inner mouth lining on another object. Is it possible to hide all skin vertices except the lips area while I'm working on the inner mouth object? (I know I can split or duplicate the lips mesh off the face and just hide the full-face object, but I want to know if I can avoid having to delete another object later.)

For instance, I would like something like this:

[image]

... while I'm working on the inner mouth (pink object).

If I attempt to work on the mouth without doing something about the face skin (clip mask is imprecise), I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the vertices you want to see:

[image]

Assign them to a vertex group:

[image]

Add a *Mask* modifier to the object, using the vertex group:

[image]

When you quit to the *Object Mode*, or if you enable the modifier's visibility in *Edit Mode* [image], you should see the difference:

[image]

Comment: Perfect; thanks! Jw, would the armature (not VG) version hide everything not rigged to the specified bone?

Comment: @Nintendraw yes, it would show (or hide, if you use the *invert* button) vertices associated with the active bone.

Comment: Odd that it's not simpler especially for temporary "hides".  Mesh -> Hide -> HideSelected only works while in Edit mode, Editing the object you want partially hidden.